# React date range highlights all dates when the value is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-date-range

I'm working with this library and ran into a problem.
When I put endDate and startDate in the dates - null - all dates are highlighted as selected, how to solve this? By selected I mean adding spans with class `.rdrInRange`

can be solved in this way, but in this case, the end date is supposedly already selected, and you have to click on any date to make it the start date and not the end date, in general, a whole history of bugs. Also, if I give endDaye null and leave `startDate` as `new Date()`, then after `startDate` all dates will be highlighted

```
   const [datepicker, setDatepicker] = useState([
        {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date(''),
            key: 'selection',
        },
    ]);
```

I tried setting `null` for both the end date and the start date, or for both, but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
setRange([
    {
      startDate: null,
      endDate: new Date(""),
      key: "selection",
    },
]);
```